# What constitutes a duplicate closure

Tags: discussion

I checked the front page of c++ threads and I worked out two problems. Each time I did and tried to submit my work the question s were closed.also, in both cases they were closed about the time I started to work on the problem. I want to be clear but I don't even believe that these questions were duplicates because the solutions were not directly answered by the mods.

This is a strange coincidence for me because both my answers used complete code implementations but the mods just closed it for some arbitrarily related question existing.

I would really appreciate help clarifying these incidences and I'm looking forward to your correspondence.

P.S.
The links in contestion are for,

[If n is an integer how to find k such that |n-2^k| is the smallest possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64808825/if-n-is-an-integer-how-to-find-k-such-that-n-2k-is-the-smallest-possible)

[C++: How to round a double to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695329/c-how-to-round-a-double-to-an-int)
Edit 1:
Thank you to the mod that migrated my question the the proper thread and thank you chat for your understanding. I am not used to the mobile version of the site and the tablature is quite different.

Comment: "but the mods just closed it for some arbitrarily related question existing." the duplicates are about similar questions not arbitrary

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP isn't asking about questions of their own that were closed; they're asking about *other people's questions* that they were trying to answer, but that were closed as duplicates before they could do so.

Comment: The first question and its duplicate are the same problem stated in two slightly different ways. Why do you think they aren't? The second was closed as a duplicate 9 months ago. Again why do you think it's not a duplicate?

Comment: The second question, about rounding, the answers in the duplicate perfectly well answers the question "how to round a double to an int". Why would this closure be considered wrong? If you had new and better solutions than presented in *either* question, then you could post an answer to the "original" question instead.

Comment: “I want to be clear but I don't even believe that these questions were duplicates because the solutions were not directly answered by the mods.” - At least one of those questions absolutely was not closed by a moderator.  The user who closed your question as a duplicate of an existing question has a gold badge in C++.  What this means is that particular user has written enough answers, that have been well received, they have been given extraordinary latitude to close questions as a duplicate of another question on Stack Overflow.  A gold badge is the closest thing to recognizing a SME in a tag

Comment: The other question was closed 9 months ago by 5 separate users, and failed to be reopened, by another set of users.  It’s time to move on to some other questions as those are both clearly a duplicate of an existing question.  **Feel free to answer the original question of those duplicates**

Comment: @some programmer dude you seem to be confusing an answer with an explanation because the difference in the steps are actually just as if not more important than the answer itself

Comment: @gnat this is probably the most related response. Thank you .

Comment: ChrisHoy the edit necessary to make question "clearly not a duplicate" (as explained in suggested duplicate linked by @gnat) is likely too drastic to be accepted. Please make sure to read it carefully and decide if it is a solution that works for you or you need some other alternative. (Conveniently reading that answer explains how you should edit *this* post if you don't think suggested duplicate answers your question here)

Comment: *"in both cases they were closed about the time I started to work on the problem"* That second question was closed 9 months ago. How long, exactly, did it take for you to compose your answer?

Comment: @CodyGray ["chris-hoy: Member for 10 months"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12728034/chris-hoy) - so it is plausible that the first case indeed happened 9 month ago but was not enough pain to ask on meta *at that time*... I.e. I tend to ask after about 3-5 cases that cause unpleasant experience (like question deleted instantly after an answer is posted).

Comment: @CodyGray No, not 9 months. **I've merely reduped it to show the new banner. It was originally duped in 2012.** See revs https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9695329/revisions

Answer (score 13):

Let me try to address why I closed the first of the two questions:

[If n is an integer how to find k such that |n-2^k| is the smallest possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64808825)

The OP on that post asked how to find the largest power of 2 less than another number. The duplicate target answers that comprehensively, and I saw no reason to leave the post open. One factor that would have swayed me to leave it open, is if the OP had made a partial attempt at solving the problem, in which case none of the solutions in the target may have solved their specific problem. However, there was no such attempt, and hence no specific problem that is not covered in the duplicate.

I appreciate that you spent some time coming up with a full working solution, and are disappointed that the post was closed before you had a chance to answer it. If you didn't know that the post was a duplicate, then it can be frustrating to have your effort go to waste.

However, since the target is actually asking the same question, your answer is likely to be applicable on that post as well. Take a little time to customize the answer for the target question, and also make sure that there isn't already an answer that repeats what you want to say. Once you've checked those things, you can go ahead and post your answer there.

Finally, I'm not a moderator, although the ability to single-handedly close questions as duplicates might appear to be a moderator level power. That power is handed to users who demonstrate that they are experts in a particular subject, and doesn't grant them any power other than the ability to close questions as duplicates, and only in the tags in which they have earned that power.

Comment: I'm not convinced you actually understand the difference between a duplicate and a similar post. I was on a c++ forum. By your logic, anyone that posts anything even remotely similar is a duplicate. Whether it is written in a different language, pseudo code, or just pure rhetoric.

Comment: @ChrisHoy The degree of similarity between any two posts lies on a spectrum, and it's not always clear at what point on that spectrum a post can be considered a duplicate. In this case however, given the degree of similarity, there is no doubt in my mind that the post is a duplicate of the marked target.

Comment: that would depend on your objectivity. Whether or not you agree ,In either case, is actually not related to the question.

Comment: @ChrisHoy Your question is asking about the criteria for a particular duplicate closure. Deciding to close as a duplicate is indeed a subjective decision, and I have explained my reasoning in this case. Whether or not I agree with the closure, and why, seems to be exactly what your question is asking.

Comment: @ChrisHoy maybe you misunderstand. Whether cigien thinks those question are duplicates is very much related to your question, because having the ability to close questions as duplicate sets users in a position to use that power

Answer (score 8):

Just for clarity, the closer of the first question you linked is not a moderator but an 'ordinary' (pardon the phrase) user, who happens to be an expert in C++ (indicated by the Gold tag badge).

The second question's closer *is* a moderator ... but one who knows enough about programming to recognize that it had already been well-answered elsewhere (it may even have been flagged as a duplicate by a user without close-vote privileges, which would have brought it to his attention).

But, for *either* of those questions, if you believe you can post an answer that is either *different from* or *better than* any of those already there for the linked duplicates, then feel free to do so on *those* posts. (In your first case, note that there is actually a short 'chain' of duplicate links - but you can still post an answer to the question at the end of the chain.)

Comment: In such a case as mention, the problem would be my explanation loses context and may not even be valid –

Comment: If your explanation loses context and fails to answer the duplicate it probably didn’t answer the question you wanted to answer.

Comment: So if I answered how to multiply but the answer was in how to add you'd say I'm wrong too.

Comment: @ChrisHoy - If your answer doesn’t answer the question than absolutely.  **You can still answer the original question with the answer you wanted to provide.**. Have you done that?